# Updateing code to swift 4 results in an error message

Tags: swift, xcode9, swift4

I wan to update this code to swift 4:

```
rc = select(socket_fd + 1, readfd, writefd, NULL, &timeout);

return rc;
  }
```

But I get two errors:

> Declaration of 'select' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.sys.time' before it is required
>   Implicit declaration of function 'select' is invalid in C99

How can I can fix this?

Comment: @aaron yes, with your answer fixing my problem, thank you

Answer (score 8):

Add this near the top of your file:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
```